# SQL Server 2012: get usage statistics for database objects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

To find out how often SQL Server users use certain objects (mostly views), I would like to log who queried the object when. If possible, I would also like to indicate in the log whether the object was called directly or if the query was part of a chain. I suspect that policies can be of use here, but did not find an example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Audits" in the server and database security sections in Management Studio. We are using Enterprise Edition, so "Fine Grained Auditing" is available to us. It covers the requirements in question, even including the sql statement used to query the object.

Other editions offer "Basic Auditing", not sure how much that will give you.